# Как отключить заголовок React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigationbar

Есть ли возможность в react native navigation отключить заголовок на одной из страниц? У меня есть 4 экрана на 3 из них должен быть заголовок, а вот на 1 не должно быть, есть ли какие-нибудь свойства у bottom tab navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, какой компонент вы используете. Для Tab.Screen используется ключ **options**, в нем указывается отображение заголовка через **headerShow**. Чтобы получить больше информации - обратитесь непосредственно к документации компонента.

Для Tab.Screen необходимо прописать следующее - `options={{headerShown: false }}`

Ниже пример оформления

[image: пример использования]

Comment: 1. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. 2. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.